# Floor value of number in Angular 8

Tags: html, typescript, angular8

I was trying to convert tha value of number that is in decimal form to whole number.

Using angular pipe method `{{myNumber | number: '1.0-0.}}` it returns rounded off number.

Example: for `number = 3.8` it is returning `4` but i want floor value `3`.

How can I get floor value of any number in angular 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To compute a floor value without any extra functions is fairly simple. Just simply use this line to compute the floor value of the number:

```
number - number % 1
```